# Transform monthly data to the weekly data based on categorical value

Tags: preprocessing, transformation, data-table

I have monthly data like this which is hours:

```
month,hours
1,20
2,19.5
3,21
...
```

I have weekly data like this which is quantities of the asset:

```
week,danger,warning,safe
1,1,13,127
2,1,14,126
3,1,13,129
4,2,13,149
...
```

I expect I have hours data in weekly based on weekly data above where it weighted by danger, warning, and safe. So I expect like this:

```
week,hour
1,5.1
2,5.2
3,4.9
4,4,8
...
```

Sum of first 4 weeks is actually data in monthly which is 20.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.